# Fade in links in sequence with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to figure out how to fade in my links one at a time. I could fade them all in, but I just want the aesthetics of one at a time. I'd even love to have them all slide out one at a time from one another, but I understand that is difficult. At least for me to go about writing. This is just a excerpt from my code handling the navigation.

http://jsfiddle.net/dpzPs/

```
$(document).read(function () {
    $.each(['#href1',
            '#href2',
            '#href3',
            '#href4',
            '#href5'], function (i, l) {

        $(l).fadeTo('slow', 1.0).delay(200);

    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could also do:

```
(function fadeLink($){
    $.eq(0).fadeTo("slow", 1, function(){
        ($=$.slice(1)).length && fadeLink($);
    });
})($('ul > li'));
```

Demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VLUz2/)

Comment: That is pretty efficient. I would have never got that short code on my own. Lol

Comment: Programming isn’t a golf competition. This solution is convoluted.

Comment: It most definitely is, however it is well formed and works great, saves up space too.

Answer (score 2):

The `.delay()` function creates a delay before the next animation on the *same* element. Try instead using `setTimeout()`:

```
$(document).ready(function () { // note: you had a typo "read" instead of "ready"
    $.each(['#href1',
            '#href2',
            '#href3',
            '#href4',
            '#href5'], function (i, l) {

        setTimeout(function(){
            $(l).fadeTo('slow', 1.0);
        }, i * 500);
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dpzPs/1/

Note that if you give your `ul` an id you can simplify your JS by saying:

```
$("#idOfUL li").each(...
```

...instead of having to list out all of the li elements' ids.

Comment: I thought I could use each, I tried a couple versions but figured it didn't work that way.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think `setInterval()` is better than `setTimeout()` for this kind of animation. [Here’s why](http://stackoverflow.com/a/731625/704015).

Comment: @Mysteryos - my fiddle works fine for me, both in Chrome on my laptop and in Miren on my phone.

Comment: @JezenThomas - I didn't find that link entirely convincing. I find that using setInterval almost always results in messier code, and historically some browsers didn't handle it well if you changed to another browser tab and later returned.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution.

```
var i = 0, // a counter
    $ul = $('ul'), // save a reference to your ul
    l = $('li', $ul).length, // count the list items
    timer = setInterval(function(){
        if (i === l) clearInterval(timer); // Stop the timer if we've faded all elements in
        $('li', $ul).eq(i).animate({opacity:1}, 160);
        i++; // increment counter
}, 200); // run the function in the setInterval once every 200ms
```

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Nh9au/).